# PHP giving blank page with the following code with errors turned on

Tags: php

I know this question keeps getting asked, but as far as i can see its just a syntax error and I cant see it. The code is as follows

on index.php:

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE); ?>

<? require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/WestAncroftSettings.php' ); ?>


<?php include("$ACCESS_PATH" . "/WestAncroft2/Pages/Main/Main.php");?>
```

and on WestAncroftSettings.php:

```
<?php $ACCESS_PATH = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/WestAncroft2'; ?>

<?php $IMAGE_PATH = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/WestAncroft2/images'; ?>
```

and on Main.php:

```
<? require($_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT] . '/WestAncroftSettings.php' ); ?>
```

If you want the rest of the content on the pages just ask.

Comment: perhaps short tags are turned off? try using `<?php` throughout. also, `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]` should have quotes around `DOCUMENT_ROOT` (although this just throws a notice).

Comment: Do you actually output anything to the browser? All I see in your code is includes which, in turn, include stuff but don't contain anything for the user to look at.

Comment: he's outputting a bunch of tabs and newlines ... could be you just need to remove the blank space before the first <?php ... while you'e at it, remove all the other <?, <?php and ?> calls... you only need a single opening tag, no closing tag

Comment: I made these changes but its still not working. Im now using <?php throughout instead of <?

Comment: @Prisoner I narrowed it down to the following line in index.html. 
<?php include("$ACCESS_PATH". "/Pages/Main/Main.php"); ?>

Can you see what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The second example of this line has missing quotes and agree with Prisoner - check short tag settings. It's advisable to use long tag names in case you change servers at some point in the future

```
<?php require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/WestAncroftSettings.php' ); ?>
```

Comment: I made these changes but still no luck :-(

Answer (score 0):

It is a typo indeed

```
<? require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/WestAncroftSettings.php' ); ?>
```

should be

```
<?php require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/WestAncroftSettings.php' ); ?>
```

and later in your code you have the same line again without `<?php` and your missing quotes around `DOCUMENT_ROOT`

Answer (score 0):

You can use short form `(<? ?>)` of PHP's open tag by enabling the "short_open_tag" to 1 in php.ini file.
After change, keep in mind to restart the Apache server.

Then you can use `(<? ?>)` and `(<?php ?>)` both in your project.

But bear in mind that If you want to use PHP in combination with XML, you can disable this option in order to use `<?xml ?>` inline. Otherwise, you can print it with PHP, for example:
 `<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>'; ?>`.